# how can i solve this R problem dependency 'animation' is not available for package 'gganimate'

Tags: r, dictionary, gganimate

when I try to run the code for  "***Animating the map using gganimate*** ", these errors keep showing up, and I don't know what to do anymore I've tried to install gganimate v  0.1.1 but still, it won't work so please if you could help me it would be much appreciate

[image: enter image description here(screen capture)]

Comment: Have you tried installing  animation directly?   `install.packages(animatation)` ?

Comment: it seems you are looking at a tutorial for an old version of gganimate... a lot of commands have changed, and I'd strongly suggest you to find some more updated tutorial and use the current version of gganimate

Comment: @G5W thank u very much , now this error is gone thanks to you    {
                  Error in ani.options(interval = 0.2) : 
                   could not find function "ani.options"  }   
but i still have this error showing up 
 >gganimate(map)
       Error: It appears that you are trying to use the old API, which has been 
                    deprecated.
          Please update your code to the new API or install the old version of gganimate
          from https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/releases/tag/v0.1.1